# Is there any performance boost in storing the return value of a function by reference?

Tags: c++, reference, return-value

Is there any performance boost in storing the return value of a function by reference? I mean is the following code preferred because it prevents copying the return value of function into the variable?

```
string Foo()
{
    string someString = "some string";
    return someString;
}

const string &str = Foo();
```

**Edit:** Although in the above example `Foo()` is returning a string, my question concerns returning other type of objects as well.

Comment: @hmjd it's fine: http://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code as it stands contains two copies in `Foo`:

(1) from a temporary object of type `string` constructed using the `const char*` constructor, to `someString`.

(2) from the variable `someString` to the temporary object that is the return value of `Foo`.

You are writing `const string &str = Foo();` instead of `const string str = Foo();` with the intention of preventing a third copy:

(3) from the temporary object that is the return value of `Foo`, to `str`.

All three copies are permitted by the standard to be elided, so the question basically is whether your compiler needs help with 3.

As a rule of thumb I would say no -- if your compiler is smart enough to elide copies 1 and 2, then likely it is smart enough to elide 3. If it is not smart enough to elide any of them, and this costs you performance, then you need to work on function `Foo` as well as on code that calls it. But this situation won't come up -- as long as you remember to turn on optimization, any real C++ compiler can do copy elision.

There could conceivably be special cases where you need to write your code carefully to help the compiler out where it fails to elide some copy that it is permitted to elide. You need to find those cases as they occur, no general coding guideline can (accurately) tell you that you need to worry about (3) but not (1) and (2).

Answer (score 4):

The way string is implemented in C++ is as an array of characters. So, when you use a reference, the primary advantage is that a member-wise copy can be avoided, and the object being pointed to is the object that has been passed in itself. This improves performance where large strings or arrays are involved. For your example, the string is really short and does not really matter! Hope this helps :).

Answer (score 3):

No.  It's possible, in fact, that there is a slight loss in performance
(although I doubt it).  About all you gain by using references in this
case is obfuscation.

Comment: I understand that the compiler would normally be able to optimize out the copy anyway, but where would the slight loss in performance come from? Implementing the reference as a pointer?

Comment: With RVO, the return value can be constructed in place - if there's such a place. If the return value is handled as a temporary bound to a reference, this may not be so simple.

Comment: @BoBTFish Formally, there are the same number of copies in both cases; using a reference means an additional level of indirection for each use of the object later.  Practically, the compiler will optimize out most of the copies, using RVO (or NRCVO, as the case may be); I would imagine that the optimizations would be the same in both cases, but if there is a difference, it will be because the reference is confusing the compiler, and preventing the optimization (which I seriously doubt).

Comment: @MSalters If the return value is a temporary initializing a reference, the compiler has to find such a place, since it has to put the temporary somewhere.  Theoretically, the special semantics associated with references could confuse the compiler, and cause an extra copy, but I doubt that such cases really occur.

Comment: I knew that RVO could be slightly finicky - e.g. many compilers couldn't mix RVO and NRVO - but assigning to a reference isn't interfering with the optimization? Good to know.

Comment: @James: do you have a compiler in mind that is smart enough to do copy elision in the case of `const string str = Foo();`, but too dumb to emit identical code for `const string &str = Foo();`? Or are you basically saying that eliding the copy from the temporary return value to `str` is an "expected" optimization, whereas in some sense treating a temporary bound to a reference the same as a variable of the same name is a "not-expected" optimization?

Comment: @SteveJessop Actually, I don't expect any compiler to do anything different in the two cases.  But a compiler which was trying to follow the abstract machine to the letter _might_ generate an additional indirection each time you used `str` later in your code.

Answer (score 2):

Today compilers are smart enough and will probably use RVO (return value optimization) in such cases. So even if returning by value no copy overhead will exist

The main rule you should follow is writing a good readable code (because code is written for people) and bother with optimizations only when it is required and only after you found the bottleneck

Comment: With or without RVO, the same number of copies are present.

Comment: @JamesKanze: The question is about preventing the copy. So i said that the copy will probably be eliminated by compiler even if returning by value

Comment: There's no reason why the compiler would eliminate it in one case, and not in the other.  RVO and NRVO should work the same in both cases.  In both cases, you have two copies in the abstract machine, and in both cases, both can be eliminated.

Answer (score 1):

Know, you will not gain perfomance boost. You can use std::move() to gain boost in this case.